# How to load external data files without defining path explicitly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, relative-path

I have a C# assembly that loads external files. This assembly is used by asp.net website.
The following is the code that loads the data files

```
string dataDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"data");
filePath = Path.Combine(dataDirectory,_fileName);
```

The component works fine in a windows app, but when I tried to use it in an asp.net website, it fails as the site could not find the data files, and it gives me the following error:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\cmictranslatorsite\20a8eddd\864b2575\assembly\dl3\5bd4a35e\8c6f79b6_98eccb01\data\file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to resolve relative physical paths in ASP.NET applications.

`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` is returning `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\cmictranslatorsite\20a8eddd\864b2575\assembly\dl3\5bd4a35e\8c6f79b6_98eccb01\`, which is the correct place where your application files copied and executed from.

If you want a directory relative to your Virtual Directory in IIS you use `Server.MapPath` to get the paths. If your `data` path is not relative perhaps `.config` file is the place to store this path. In either cases check the `app pool identity` or your `authenticated` users have appropriate access to the path you are reading from or writing to.

Comment: Could I use Server.MapPath from the dll? it is a generic component used by different apps (windows or web apps)

Comment: Yup you need to make an `optional parameter` to this code which calculates the path, then in Windows app you dont pass this parameter (or pass null) in web app pass this. or you could have `orverloads`, or whaterver makes sense in your code to accomodate one more variable to depend in your dll code.